# Best way to observe periodically updated data

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a workmanager which run after every 7 days. I want to know what will be the best way to observe this data and update the UI or DB changes accordingly .

Answer (score 1):

I would say DB because after 7 days no UI might be active, but you have to save the state. Moreover, nowadays, Room provides an easy way to implement it.
It would also be nice to have a notification implemented to let a user know about some results.